# Run an executable from WPF Browser Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have deployed my WPF Browser App (XBAP) in a WebSite on IIS.
The XBAP is running under a website.
I want to access and exe on Server and execute it from this WPF app.

I have written code for this, which check for a file (exe) on a path on the server.
But instead of searching for the path on the serve it searches for the path on client machine and gives File not Found error.

Please let me know whether its possible to access server resource from WPF browser application hosted on a website.
If yes please provide a code sample.

Comment: XBAP run on client side, not server side

Comment: is there any way to access server resource or execute server exe?

Comment: XBAP can query server resources through HTTP requests for instance

Comment: have a look into RPC (Remote Procedure Calls), this should help you